# Add number, then tuple to list as a tuple, but it drops outer tuple

Tags: python, list, tuples

I am trying to add a tuple of a (number, (tuple)), but it drops the outer tuple.

How do I change the code so that l1 comes out looking like L2?
It appears to drop the outer tuple and convert it to list elements?  How do I stop that?  Better yet, why is it happening?

```
l1 = []
t1 = (1.0 , (2.0,3.0))
l1.extend((t1))
t2 = (4.0 , (5.0,6.0))
l1.extend(t2)
print(l1)

l2 = [(1.0, (2.0,3.0)),
      (4.0, (5.0,6.0))]
print(l2)
```

l1 comes out as [1.0, (2.0, 3.0), 4.0, (5.0, 6.0)]

l2 comes out as  [(1.0, (2.0, 3.0)), (4.0, (5.0, 6.0))]

Comment: Use `append` instead of `extend`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use append:

```
l1 = []
t1 = (1.0, (2.0, 3.0))
l1.append((t1))
t2 = (4.0, (5.0, 6.0))
l1.append(t2)
print(l1)

l2 = [(1.0, (2.0, 3.0)),
      (4.0, (5.0, 6.0))]
print(l2)
```

Answer (score 1):

Changing it to append() does the trick.

```
l1 = []
t1 = (1.0 , (2.0,3.0))
l1.append((t1))
t2 = (4.0 , (5.0,6.0))
l1.append(t2)
print(l1)

l2 = [(1.0, (2.0,3.0)),
      (4.0, (5.0,6.0))]
print(l2)
```

l1 - [(1.0, (2.0, 3.0)), (4.0, (5.0, 6.0))]

l2 - [(1.0, (2.0, 3.0)), (4.0, (5.0, 6.0))]

Append adds the data structure as is to the end of the list, extend extracts the iterables. To understand it better [append vs. extend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/252703/append-vs-extend)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using both `extend()` and `append()`. The problem with your code using `extend()` is that Python does not recognize `()` as a tuple, even if there is only one element in it. However, it does recognize `(,)` as an empty tuple:

```
l1 = []
t1 = (1.0 , (2.0,3.0))
# Note the extra comma
l1.extend((t1,))
t2 = (4.0 , (5.0,6.0))
# Note the extra enclosing parentheses and comma
l1.extend((t2,))
print(l1)

l2 = [(1.0, (2.0,3.0)),
      (4.0, (5.0,6.0))]
print(l2)
```

The other way, as Vedang Mehta has said, is to use append:

```
l1 = []
t1 = (1.0 , (2.0,3.0))
l1.append(t1)
t2 = (4.0 , (5.0,6.0))
l1.append(t2)
print(l1)

l2 = [(1.0, (2.0,3.0)),
      (4.0, (5.0,6.0))]
print(l2)
```

Both will give you the result of:

```
[(1.0, (2.0, 3.0)), (4.0, (5.0, 6.0))]
[(1.0, (2.0, 3.0)), (4.0, (5.0, 6.0))]
```